# Batch file : get the creation date of a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to get the creation date of a folder in pure batch file (no power script)? In particular, I would like to get it inside this for loop:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\asdf\*"') DO CALL :loopbody "%%~tG" "%%G"
```

This loop call a 'function' with the modification date of the folder as the first parameter and the path of the folder as the second parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ('dir /ad /od /tc "dirname"') do (
  echo %%A-%%B
  goto :end_loop
)
:end_loop
```

Try this.Result will depend on your time settings and probably you'll need to tune the tokens and delims.It's possible also with `WMIC` and hybrid jscript/vbscript ,but will need a few minutes to create a script.

**EDIT** with wmic:

```
WMIC path Win32_Directory WHERE name='C:\\SomeDir' get creationdate
```

**EDIT** Here are some ready to use scripts using different methods to acquire file or directory time stamps :

1. [fileModifiedTime.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat) - gets last modified time of file with settings independent format.Based on **robocopy**
2. [fileTimes.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat) - gets file time stamps with **WMIC**
3. [dirTimes.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/dirTimes.bat)  - gets directory time stamps with **WMIC**
4. [fileTimesJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/fileTImesJS.bat) - file time stamps with **jscript**
5. [dirTimesJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/dirTimesJS.bat)  - directory time stamps with **jscript**
6. [fileTimesNET.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/fileTimesNET.bat) - file time stamps with **.NET**
7. [dirTimesNET.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/dirTimesNET.bat)  - dir time stamps with **.NET**

Comment: I think `die` should be `dir`

Comment: This seems like a good solution but is there a way to avoid the two last lines of the dir command. The 2 last lines are something like this for me: "0-File(s) 0 bytes" and "6-Dir(s) 54,315,020,288 bytes free"

Comment: After trying both npocmaka and Endoro solutions, I had to give the accepted answer to npocmaka because it's much faster than Endoro's solution. Plus, it's much simpler. The downside of npocmaka solution is that it return 3 useless lines.

Answer (score 4):

```
    @ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
    CD "StartFolder"
    FOR /D /R %%G in (*) DO (
        SET "FileName=%%~G"
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        FOR /F %%H IN ('wmic fsdir where name^="!FileName:\=\\!" get creationdate^|find "."') DO SET "cdate=%%H"
        CALL :loopbody "!cdate:~6,2!/!cdate:~4,2!/!cdate:~0,4!-!cdate:~8,2!:!cdate:~10,2!:!cdate:~12,2!" "!FileName!"
        ENDLOCAL
    )
    GOTO:EOF

    :loopbody
    ECHO %~1 "%~2"
    EXIT /B
```

Comment: +1 but looks to complicated.Why just don't you use `%%~dpfnG` instead of dir?

Comment: `%%~dpfnG` ? Sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: Is there a way to get the creation time also?

Comment: @Endoro you can get the full path to the directory without calling the dir command.

Comment: @npocmaka oh, I see you mean `/D /R "C:\SomeDir" %%G in (*)` , added creation time.