# Delete all files inside all folders with a specific name with date before today

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my hard disk I have the following structure:

```
ROOTFOLDER   
├───FOLDER1
│   └───TMPFOLDER
│       ├───FOLDERTODELETE1
│       ├───FOLDERTODELETE2
│       └───FOLDERTODELETE3
├───FOLDER2
│   └───TMPFOLDER
│       ├───FOLDERTODELETE4
│       └───FOLDERTODELETE5
└───FOLDER3
    └───TMPFOLDER
        ├───FOLDERTODELETE6
        ├───FOLDERTODELETE7
        └───FOLDERTODELETE8
```

I need to create a kind of script (I was thinking about a batch file, but any other solution will be appreciated) to **delete all folders within each folders with a specific name** (in this case `TMPFOLDER`) and **created before today**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following to your needs the batch script below will do what you need. Remove the `echo` in front of the `rmdir` command if it's okay for you. Take care that the script uses the current working directory. Remove `/q` if you want to be asked for each directory that should be deleted:

```cmd
@echo off

set "tmpfolder=TMPFOLDER"

for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('dir /b /a:d "*"') do (
   for /f "tokens=*" %%E in ('dir /b /a:d "%%D\*" ^| findstr /l /x %tmpfolder%') do (
      echo Found temp folder: "%%D\%%E"
      for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /a:d "%%D\%%E\*"') do (
         echo rmdir /s /q "%%D\%%E\%%F"
      )
   )
)
```

**Edit #1:**

The above script does **not** take care of the creation date of the folder that should be removed. You want only folders to be deleted which have a creation date before today. The following script takes care of that. Look [here how to get dates of folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520486/8051589) and [here how to compare dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649624/8051589):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "tmpfolder=TMPFOLDER"

for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('dir /b /a:d "*"') do (
   for /f "tokens=*" %%E in ('dir /b /a:d "%%D\*" ^| findstr /x /c:"%tmpfolder%"') do (
      rem echo Found temp folder: "%%D\%%E"
      for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /a:d "%%D\%%E\*"') do (
         rem echo    Subfolder: "%%F"
         set "curdate=!date!"
         set "dirdate="
         echo GETDATE
         call :getdate dirdate "%%D\%%E\%%F"
         set "dirdate=!dirdate:~-4!!dirdate:~3,2!!dirdate:~0,2!"
         set "curdate=!curdate:~-4!!curdate:~3,2!!curdate:~0,2!"

         rem echo    dirdate: "!dirdate!"
         rem echo    curdate: "!curdate!"
         rem echo.

         if [!dirdate!] LSS [!curdate!] (
            echo rmdir /s /q "%%D\%%E\%%F"
         )
      )
   )
)
goto :EOF

:getdate
rem call: getdate date(dstParam) folder(srcParam)
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1 delims= " %%A in ('dir /a:d /o:d /t:c "%~2"') do (
   set "%~1=%%A"
   goto :EOF
)
```

---

Command reference links from [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/):

- [DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [goto](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [rem](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)

Comment: I extended my answer with a second variant of the script posted before. That version will take care of the creation date. Test it and report. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works great! Only one question: this batch works only if TMPFOLDER is on the 2nd level of the structure?

Comment: Yes because `findstr /x /c:"%tmpfolder%"` is involved in the 2nd `for /f` loop. Adapt the script as you need it.

Comment: I've a problem with `dirdate` value: it always return a blank value from `getdate` function. Within the function the value is correct (I checked it using a log). Could be the problem on the `set` command within the function?

Comment: @Fabio: I corrected the batch script and edited my answer. I was missing `EnableDelayedExpansion`. Now it will work without any problems: You can output the dates (if you want to see them) by removing the `rem` in front of the `echo dirdate: ...` etc. I added the `EnableDelayedExpansion` to the command reference.

Answer (score 1):

Although an answer has already been accepted, I have decided to post this untested idea as an alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC OS Get LocalDateTime') Do For %%B In (%%~nA
) Do Set "TD=%%B" & Set "TD=!TD:~,8!"

For /D /R "ROOTFOLDER" %%A In ("TMPFOLD?R") Do If /I "%%~nxA"=="TMPFOLDER" (
    Set "FP=%%~pA" & Set "FP=!FP:\=\\!"
    WMIC FSDir Where "Path='!FP!' And FileName='TMPFOLDER'" Get CreationDate^
     |FindStr/B "%TD%">Nul||Echo=RD/S/Q "%%A")
Timeout -1
```

You may need to change `ROOTFOLDER` and all instances of `TMPFOLDER` as necessary, *remembering to use a `?` to replace one of the characters in the first instance of `TMPFOLDER`*.

If the output appears to be correct, remove the last line and `Echo=` from the line above it.