# How to find whether a particular folder has modifications on today using batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, windows-10

I have a folder and using batch file I want to know whether its modified(any file created or modified in it) today or not.

Below is command to get count of all files in a folder. I am new in batch files and don't know how to get it, pl help.

```
set MyFolder=D:\folder1
SET file_Cnt=0
for %%o IN (%MyFolder%/*.*) DO (      
      SET /A file_Cnt=file_Cnt+ 1    
)
echo %file_Cnt%
```

**Edit :-**
I got this solution but only problem is I want to set a variable(for total count of files modified) here which can be used later.

```
forfiles /S /P "%MyFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" | find /C "_"
```

**Edit2:-** I have tried below commands to set the variable but not working.

```
forfiles /S /P "%MyFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" | find /C "_"
echo %_%      --getting echo off message

for /F %%N in ('forfiles /S /P "%MyFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" ^| find /C "_"') do set "NUMBER=%%N"
echo %NUMBER% --getting echo off message
echo %%N --getting echo off message
```

Comment: The last approach (`for /F`) should work even if no files are found. Have you tried this separately, or within some other code? Perhaps you are facing a totally different problem (e. g., lack of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html))...

Comment: I also have tried delayed expansion but still getting echo off

Comment: And I don't think this condition is working at all

Comment: Perhaps you should ask [@mandeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7820310/mandeep?tab=questions) to collaborate.

Comment: Thanks @Compo, actually I am following mandeep's question. And I resolved it.

Comment: @Mona, if you've found a solution to your own, and consequently mandeep's issue, why not post the solution in this and/or those questions, marking your own as accepted.

Comment: I've posted my answer @Compo, its working. Last thing which I want to get filename(s) which has been modified, if you know please answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for /F %%N in ('forfiles /S /P "%MyFolder%" /M "*" /D +0 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" ^| find /C "_"') do (
     // we can simply get %%N here or we can also set some variable here if required.  
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use PowerShell for this.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Folder1' | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date}
```

To call from command prompt.

```
PowerShell.exe -c "Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Folder1' | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date}|measure | select -expand count"
```

Comment: can i write this line in the same batch file ?

Comment: not directly, you can use `PowerShell.exe -c 'Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Folder1' | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date}'`

Answer (score 1):

The following command gets the list of all the files from the current folder that are created on the same day.

```
for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C | findstr /C:%i /B
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: where to pass directory name? and is it provide me count or the filename ?

Comment: You can pass directory name after dir /T:C <directory name>.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output filename, you can try this command

```
for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C "C:\Test" | findstr /C:%i /B | for /f "tokens=5" %j in ('more') do @echo %j
```

Or if you want to get the count, you can try this command

```
for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C "C:\Test" | findstr /C:%i /B | find /c ":"
```

Comment: not working @nghiep... and where did you pass current date

Comment: ('date /t) is where I put the current date. You can try this command "date /t" in your command line window. The output will be like this "Sat 03/31/2018"

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer for this question could possible help you, they have scripts for getting the LastModified, LastAccessed and DateCreated from folders and files.

[Batch file : get the creation date of a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520077/batch-file-get-the-creation-date-of-a-folder)

Answer (score -3):

Below is my test result. What the error in your command, @Mona ?

[commandline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ0Ef.png)

Comment: when I write   for /F "tokens=2" %i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C "%MyFolder%" | findstr /C:%i /B | find /c ":"  then its not running and when I simply write    dir /T:C "%MyFolder%" | findstr /C:%i /B | find /c ":"  then getting error FINDSTR: argument missing after /C .... and I am working on a batch file...

Comment: In your batch file, we need to write %%i instead of %i. For example, I create test.bat with the following content. set MyFolder="C:\Test"
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do dir /T:C "%MyFolder%" | findstr /C:%%i /B | find /c ":" > C:\Test\a.txt. Then open C:\Test\a.txt to view the result after executing batch file